# is there an vim event triggered by terminal window resizing?

Tags: vim

If you resize the terminal window you're running vim (or macvim) in, is there any vimscript event that gets triggered and which you can attach autocommands to?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The event you are looking for is `VimResized`.  See `:help VimResized` for more information.

For a complete list of autocmd events and details about them individually, see `:help autocmd-events`.